# ShoeBox for cocos2d animation

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone

Is it able to use ShoeBox for cocos2d animation?
Just i like this app, it's easy to use and free.

Just bfore i use texturePacker which give's me plist format, and shoebox give's xml looks like

```
<TextureAtlas imagePath="sheet.png">
    <SubTexture name="W1001.png" x="81" y="360" width="73" height="106"/>
    <SubTexture name="W1002.png" x="83" y="130" width="76" height="106"/>
    <SubTexture name="W1003.png" x="233" y="0" width="90" height="106"/>
    <SubTexture name="W1004.png" x="0" y="136" width="81" height="106"/>
    <SubTexture name="W1005.png" x="157" y="347" width="69" height="106"/>
    <SubTexture name="W1006.png" x="0" y="360" width="78" height="105"/>
    <SubTexture name="W1007.png" x="0" y="244" width="73" height="114"/>
    <SubTexture name="W1008.png" x="401" y="0" width="75" height="117"/>
    <SubTexture name="W1009.png" x="157" y="0" width="74" height="124"/>
    <SubTexture name="W1010.png" x="81" y="0" width="74" height="127"/>
    <SubTexture name="W1011.png" x="0" y="0" width="79" height="134"/>
    <SubTexture name="W1012.png" x="325" y="0" width="74" height="122"/>
    <SubTexture name="W1013.png" x="75" y="244" width="68" height="114"/>
    <SubTexture name="W1014.png" x="161" y="126" width="77" height="105"/>
    <SubTexture name="W1015.png" x="145" y="239" width="71" height="106"/>
    <SubTexture name="W1016.png" x="228" y="233" width="68" height="106"/>
</TextureAtlas>
```

in other words, how to use this xml for cocos2d animation?

Comment: Write a converter. Shouldn't be that hard to do, the cocos2d texture atlas plist format uses the same parameters (and some additional ones you can probably just ignore / set to 0).

Comment: Yeah.. Maybe later i will do it on mac os. At the moment i start to use Zwoptex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShoeBox 3.1.0 added a cocos2d pList format export added to the "Sprite Sheet" tool.

Screenshot:
http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8382/8457718272_315955c6fa_o.jpg

It wasn't announced in a big way because I still haven't been able to test or confirm the correctness of the export myself. But I am pretty confident that the crop, x,y,.. values are correct.
If you could give this a spin and let me know if it works for you that would be nice.

Comment: thx, in new version its added.. I didn't try to do it, cuz i use to use Zwopex, but at first free time i sure will try it. Thx for your answer.